# For Ruby on Rails, how do you tell Sass to compress the generated CSS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

The following is quite cool (running on Bash):

```
$ echo -e "div\n  color: #ffffee" | sass -t compressed 
div{color:#ffe}
```

as compared to:

```
$ echo -e "div\n  color: #ffffee" | sass 
div {
  color: #ffffee; }
```

so can the `-t compressed` option be used for a Rails project -- how can it be configured?

```
-t, --style NAME      Output style. Can be nested (default), compact, 
                        compressed, or expanded.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Environment.rb (or wherever you're setting your sass options), add the following:

```
Sass::Plugin.options[:style] = :compressed
```

See the sass documentation on style ouput [here](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#output_style) and general options [here](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#options)